# how to convert oversized json to collection?

Tags: java, json

Given below code, `getArchives()` is a remote API. `getArchives()` return a oversized JSON, larger than 100 MB and maybe larger in the future.

```
public void syncArchive() {
    // the json is so large, I'm wondering it's appropriate to use java.lang.String to hold it
    String data = dataService.getArchives(); 

    // convert data to List<Archive> and then save to mysql
    ...
}
```

The `Archive` structure is below. `content`, `text1`, `text2`, `text3` are large text.

```java
public class Archive {
    private String id;
    private String name;

    // content, text1, text2, text3 are large text
    private String content;
    private String text1;
    private String text2;
    private String text3;
    ...
    private String text20;
    
    //getter and setter
    ...
}
```

Please see the `text` with number appended. This is why I say the JSON would be larger in the future. The data provider has defined stupid oversized text fields inside MySQL to store archive files. There are 20 `text` fields for backup!

And I was also asked to get the data from the `getArchives()` API, save it to our database, and the database structure and data had to be consistent with theirs.

How to convert the oversized JSON to a `List<Archive>` and then save to MySQL without `OutOfMemoryError`?

Notice that I must convert it to `List` because the DB API defined by DB department is like this:

```
Object save(String tableCode, List<Map> data);
```

So how to convert the large JSON to `List` and then throw these code to others before these data are too big to be exaggerated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So how to convert the large JSON to a `List`

Given that your goal is to upload the data to a database, the best answer is to NOT convert the JSON to a (real) `List`.  Converting to a `List` will entail converting the entire JSON to Java objects and that will consume heap space proportional to the size of the JSON.  It doesn't scale.

Instead, use a "streaming" or "event based" JSON parser to parse the JSON.  As you read each JSON object, do whatever is necessary to process it and then insert it into the database.  Then throw it away.

Examples of JSON streaming parsers include:

- implementations of JSON-P's `javax.json.stream.JsonParser`,
- the Gson `JsonReader` API, and
- the Jackson `JsonParser` API.

---

> Notice that I must convert it to List because the DB API defined by DB apartment is like this:
>
> ```
> Object save(String tableCode, List<Map> data);
> ```

Well, frankly, that is a big problem.  If the DB API only allows you to save a complete (ummm) "table", and the data for a table won't fit into memory, then you may have been given a problem with no decent solution.

Talk to the people who designed the DB API.  Ask them if they change the API to provide a more scalable way of uploading the data to the DB.

If not, one possibility would be to design and implement a *lazy* list.

- Implement a class that presents the data from the streaming parser as an `Iterator<Archive>`.
- Then implement a "list" whose `iterator()` method returns the iterator for your JSON.

Note that this approach will depend on how much `List` functionality the DB's `save` method is using.  If it uses more than just the `iterator()`, this approach may not work.